# Change font in Excel forumula bar

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, microsoft-excel-2019

Is it possible to change the font type in Excel's formula bar? I want to use a monospace font to make my formulas easier to read.

I'm using Office 365, Excel version 1904.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know you can change the default font, which will change the font in the formula bar, but it cannot be separate.  So if you want the formula bar as a monospace font the default cell font will be the same and one would then need to reformat the cells to the desired font on each new workbook.  Old workbooks will stay their font in the cells.  You can go to File→Options→General→When creating new workbooks→change the default font.

Comment: For formula bar the font is default, you cannot change it.